# Compilar módulos SCSS en componente VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, scss, laravel-mix

Tengo una plantilla modularizada que usa Sass-loader para compilar archivos scss que tiene cada componente, pero no he podido configurar webpack en laravel mix para que este funcione correctamente.

Estoy usando la versión(5.8) de laravel y Vue JS (2.5.17)

ejemplo de componente:

```
<template>
  <div :class="$style.logo">
    <div :class="$style.logoContainer">
      <img
        v-if="!settings.isMenuCollapsed || withDrawer"
        src="resources/images/logo-inverse.png"
        alt
      >
      <img
        v-if="settings.isMenuCollapsed && !withDrawer"
        src="resources/images/logo-inverse-mobile.png"
        alt
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" module>
  @import "./style.module.scss";
</style>
```

Aquí hay un componente con su archivo style.scss que se compilará como módulo. Las clases aquí deben guardarse en $style.

Yo uso estos paquetes en package.json:

```
"sass": "^1.15.2",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
```

y finalmente, mi archivo webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-alias');

mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                modules: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});

mix.alias({
  '@': '/resources/js'
})

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

La cuestión es que las clases en los archivos de componentes scss no se compilan, y por eso, las etiquetas html después de la compilación no poseen estilos, perdiendo toda la estructura de mi plantilla.

Este tiene que ser el componente del archivo compilado:

```
<div class="index_logo_hObJ1">
  <div class="index_logoContainer_1zCMH">
    <img src="resources/images/logo-inverse.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

y esto es lo que obtengo:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img src="resources/images/logo-inverse.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Como puede ver, no se inyectaron clases en divs, y no obtengo errores al compilar, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: no veo donde podría estar el problema, pero hay un issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/771 donde a su vez referencian la sección "migrando desde v14": https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/migrating.html#notable-breaking-changes

Comment: solo se me ocurre que el error esta en la configuración de módulos en `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: Podrías probar algo como `.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css', {modules:true})` pero suena improbable

Comment: si, sin ninguna novedad!, tampoco pude encontrar nada de información respecto a este caso

Comment: Ya instalaste `node-sass`?

Comment: @RimuruTempest así es ya esta instalado, de momento tampoco e tenido errores, simplemente los estilos modulares no se compilan

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a esta [documentación](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass) explican como puedes usar SASS en Vue.

Solo debes instalar estas dependencias

```sh
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass vue-style-loader
```

Y tu archivo `webpack.mix.js` debería verse así:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
                modules: true
            }
          },
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Comment: esta configuración no funciona con laravel-mix

Comment: @FeRcHo que error te da?

Comment: @FeRcHo actualice mi respuesta, espero te sirva ;)

Comment: siguen sin funcionar, ya había probado esta configuración peo aun no se compilan las clases

Answer (score 1):

En tu archivo webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

//esto esta por defecto
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')

//esto lo haces para compilar archivos js
mix.scripts([
    'resources/carpetaJs/archivo.js'
], 'public/js/all.js');

//Esto es lo que necesitas, pues te explicare un poco y no sera necesario que lo llames en tus componentes
mix.styles([
    'resources/carpetaScss/archivo1.scss',
    'resources/carpetaCss/archivo2.css',
    'resources/carpetaLess/archivo3.less',
], 'public/css/all.css');
```

Agrega una carpeta para las buenas practicas, ahí dentro agrega tu archivo scss y escribe el código de arriba...
Por último escribe: npm run watch o npm run dev
Espero te sirva....

Comment: en realidad necesito compila estilos scss modulares

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a extraerlo en un archivo separado, al tener un .scss igual tu loader salta:

```
<style lang="scss" src="./style.scss"></style>
```